# When are two rotating shafts at different speeds both at 360 degrees?

Tags: classical-mechanics, rotational-dynamics, rotation, rotational-kinematics

I have two rotating shafts that are both oriented at 0 degrees when a test starts. Then assume both shafts instantly start rotating at 60 RPM. One is maintained at a constant 60 RPM and the other starts at 60 RPM but then slowly decreases at a decreasing rate (it's non-linear) in rotational speed over time. I have a sensor that measures the 0 degree crossing of each shaft with respect to time. This pulse train is what I'm using to calculate the RPM vs. time.

What I'm looking to do is calculate at what time(s) both shafts will cross 0 degrees at the same time. I can do this by just recording the data forever and then look for when the 0 degree sensor pulse occurs for both at the same time, but in some instances that could be a VERY long time. I'd like to run this hypothetical test for a minute or two, get a good idea of the decreasing RPM trend, fit a curve to it and then somehow use that to calculate at what time(s) in the future the 0 crossings will occur. But even if I fit a curve to the data, I still need a little help figuring out how to use that equation to predict those time(s). Any help/ideas?

Notes

- This is purely hypothetical, so please don't worry about gravity or friction or anything like that.
- I have the ability to theoretically measure other aspects of this problem if that would help.
- As soon as I have 10 mana points (or "reputation") on Stack Exchange I will upload a picture showing the plot of each shaft's RPM vs time for your reference.

Comment: If the slowdown is non-linear, then how do you know that they will ever coincide?  It seems possible that they never will.   This seems more like one of those "when do two hands on a clock cross" math problems rather than physics.

Comment: That's a fair question. It turns out that I know for a fact there is at least one point in time at which they coincide. The above problem is actually the reverse of something else, so I can very easily check that there is in fact a coinciding time, but not what that coinciding time is.

Answer (score 0):

First what you have to do is the accuracy you want to find the coincidenc between the two events. For example, should the allowed angle between the zero positions of the two shafts be 1° or should it be 0.01°? Next step will a PC on which you run the equations for both shafts with numerical steps (interval of time) of this accuracy. For the constant rotating shaft with 60 RPM = 1/s one simple gets

- **interval of time = 1 second/360** for the accuracy of 1° or
- **interval of time=1second/(360/0.01)** for the accuracy of 0.01°.

Comment: Let's just assume I pick an accuracy of 0.01 degrees. I can set the delta t in the simulation.

Comment: @RGames What you want to say?